# Photoshop JavaScript: Delete all guides?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I can only find out a way to remove a single guide from the layout:

```
activeDocument.guides[0].remove();
```

This targets a single guide using an index. Isn't there a menu I can call to clear all guides at once?

Comment: You mean a loop? like `forEach` or `for` or `while`?

Comment: No, I mean just delete every guide, with one command. The way Photoshop scripting works, it refuses to accept a command that applies to all guides. It requires an index. I just want one single command that deletes all the guides. There is a menu command called "Clear Guides." I need to know if I can simply invoke that menu item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`activeDocument.guides.removeAll()`](https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/uxp/2022/ps_reference/classes/guides/#removeall)

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, you had to remove the guides in reverse order:

```
// function CLEAR ALL GUIDES ()
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
function clear_all_guides()
{
  var numGuides = activeDocument.guides.length;
  if (numGuides == 0) return;

  // Delete 'em in reverse order 
  for (var i = numGuides -1; i >=0; i--)
  {
    app.activeDocument.guides[i].remove();
  }
}
```

which is the same as

```
 var idclearAllGuides = stringIDToTypeID( "clearAllGuides" );
 executeAction( idclearAllGuides, undefined, DialogModes.NO );
```

Comment: Or `while (app.activeDocument.guides.length) { app.activeDocument.guides[0].remove()}`

Comment: That works too! However, #fearofthewhileloop in Photoshop :)

Comment: It may be slightly less performant  since it needs to shift the array with every `remove()`

Comment: It may well be. However I've a _feeling_ that `activeDocument.guides.removeAll()` is new and won't work on older versions of PS.

Comment: It was added in [Photoshop 23.2](https://github.com/AdobeDocs/uxp-photoshop/commit/1394038e4aaa603c79579ec7e02e3361146129b7#diff-258f07f2468dc6648986473255d64c1b448de7297618f8c5fb4fea04ca492550R79-R83)